# How to define the input of computable function or Turing machine over real numbers

Tags: reference-request, arithmetic-geometry, computational-complexity, computability-theory, computational-number-theory

Computation or computability over $\mathbb{N}$ can be extended to computation or computability over $\mathbb{R}$ or even computation or computability over $\mathbb{C}$.The following is a formal definition in *An Introduction to Kolmogorov Complexity and Its Applications* by Ming Li and Paul M.B. Vitányi:

**Definition** A real number $x = 0.x_1x_2 \dots$ is lower semicomputable if the set of rationals below $x$ is recursively enumerable.
 A number $-x$ is upper semicomputable if $x$ is lower semicomputable. A number $x$ is computable,equivalently, recursive, if it is both lower semicomputable and upper semicomputable

We may have other different definition that is closer to our intuition:

**Definition** if Given $r \in \mathbb{R}$, $\forall i\in \mathbb{N}$,there is Turing machine $\mathbf{M}$ that outputs $i$ bit of $r$,$r$ is computable real

By intuition,we know  Universal Turing machine takes different time and space to output in the  same amount of first bits(that is,any first $n$ bits) for different reals  like natural numbers ,quotients,algebraic numbers and computable transcendental numbers,when we give an input to compute a real.for example,computation of $\sqrt{2}$ and $e$ may take different times and spaces(outputing same amount of first bits for $\sqrt{2}$ and $e$ ).

But we can give an algebraic equation as input to compute an algebraic number like $\sqrt{2}$ or an close form like $(1+\frac{1}{x})^x$ to compute $e$.Also we can  compute $\sqrt{2}$ or $e$ with their continued fraction expansion as inputs.But different inputs to compute a same number like $e$ may take different time and space.

To measure the computational complexity of different reals,we have to give representation of reals,what representation of reals do we have to choose?Or how to define the input of computable function  or Turing machine over real numbers to measure the computational complexity of different reals? Any answers or comments or reference are welcome

Comment: Here is a relevant post and answer http://mathoverflow.net/questions/99421/computational-complexity-of-calculating-the-nth-root-of-a-real-number?rq=1,  but they are only on algebraic number and equation.

Comment: Regarding the question "what representation of reals do we have to choose", please read my answer at http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/16547/705

Comment: @AndrejBauer,thank you.I have just browsed your answer to that post.The main point is :Turing Machine can not implement the axioms for what we call reals,so to ask for a suitable representation of reals is impossible?

Comment: No, that is not the point. We *can* implement the reals, but it's a bit trickier than you'd expect. You cannot naively expect to implement equality as a boolean test, for instance, but you can implement inequality as a semidecidable test. So there are some surprises, and that's why people are so confused about computation over the reals.

Comment: @AndrejBauer,you say "We now know that an acceptable representation of the reals is one by rapid Cauchy sequences of rationals. (An important theorem states that any two representations of reals which are acceptable are actually computably isomorphic.)".Now,here we have to neglect the computational complexity of the actually computably isomorphic map or function.If we take account for the complexity of the isomorphic function,we can give hierarchy of computable reals.[cont]

Comment: [Cont]and is there any total or partial ordering between these different representation of the same real by ordering of computational complexities of the computably isomorphic functions?If so,we can choose the  least complex one as suitable representation to compare the computational complexity of reals,otherwise the comparison is meaningless.but by intuition,we know it meaningful.I am not sure if it exist,and if it is easy to get the ordering

Comment: [Cont] the existence of representation with the least computational complexity is puzzling,since we have to put restriction like length on the representation .Hence we have to take account of Kolmogorov complexity  of the representation .But I am not sure combination of computational complexity and Kolmogorov complexity will give a definition that is fit into our intuition.

Comment: And by  *Complexity and Real Computation* by Blum, Cucker, Shub, and Smale,we know the computational complexity of reals is independent of Turing Machine,it can be given a hierarchy by descriptive complexity that is something relevant to finit-model theory.But the hierarchy by descriptive complexity is coarser-grained.Maybe it can separate $NP$ and $P$,I am not sure if it can separate finer-grained complexity like $\sqrt{2}$ and $2^{\frac{1}{3}}$

Comment: I specifically preempted my comment with "regarding the question..." so as to make it clear I was not discussing complexity (although what I said still stands, except as you note, things get more complicated). Of course complexity is a very interesting issue. Some work has been done in Type Two Effectivity. Essentially, complexity on a space $X$ makes sense when each point of $X$ has compactly many representatives, see e.g. http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/als/Research/Others/schroeder-mlq04.pdf

Comment: @AndrejBauer,I see,and thank you again for your valuable comments.You know,I get a lot of knowledge from your comment and I still care how to solve my intended question . And I have just begin to browse part of pdf which you just tell me ,thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good place to start learning about different representations of reals and their computability- and complexity-theoretic consequences is Weihrauch's book *Computable Analysis*.

Comment: Thank you,Bjørn Kjos-Hanssen.It is the first time I know the book and such a domain,and it is relevant to the computational complexity of reals .But different representation of reals make the comparison of computational complexity of different reals meaningless.We have to choose a suitable one and prove it is suitable.I don't know which one is fit into those requiremen.Anyway,I have to read the book ahead.

Comment: Some words from the book:Since we are not interested in some arbitrary computability theory on $\mathbb{R}$
 we need a good justification
for the choice of the Cauchy representation (or some equivalent one).In this section we explain why the Cauchy representation is topologically natural
for the real line
 and why it is computationally natural We mention the concept
of admissible representations and formulate the important continuity theorem for
admissible representations. Finally we explain why several other representations of $\mathbb{R}$ cannot be natural.

Answer (score 2):

A good book on the *complexity* of real constants and functions is Ker-I Ko's "Computational Complexity of Real Functions", 1991.

Answer (score 1):

Another book, maybe not exactly what you want: Complexity and Real Computation, by Blum, Cucker, Shub, and Smale.

Comment: Thank you ,none.Why not to change your name into a meaningful one?

Comment: Some words from  Complexity and Real Computation:Complexity classes over a ring $R$ are classes of problems categorized according to their solvability with respect to a given machine model and prescribed resource restrictions. We have seen various such classifications in the preceding chapters. In this chapter we show that a number of classes can be characterized in terms of the "complexity" of their descriptions. This provides machine-independent characterizations of important complexity classes and sheds some light on their comparison.